# seeAllData = false vs. ConnectApi

Tags: apex, connect-api, test-data-isolation

I have a trigger on FeedItem that auto-tags a topic. It does so by creating a TopicAssignment record and inserting it via DML. The problem is that I am getting a gack if I attempt to auto-assign a topic when posting to that very same topic's feed, so I need to develop a work-around.

I can use the ConnectApi.Topics class to assign a topic. This is much cleaner, and uses about 20 lines less of code. The problem is that the ConnectApi requires seeAllData to be set to true in tests. Without it, I have about 7 failing test methods.

Alternatively, I can add a SOQL to my trigger to find out if the topic already exists for that FeedItem (which would be the case when posting to that topic's feed), and only create the TopicAssignment if it doesn't. This requires a map and a couple more for loops.

What say you? I really dislike seeAllData being set to true but I don't know that it matters that much if I'm not actually relying on data from the instance.

Comment: Since you know you're not reading any data, I'd go with the cleaner ConnectApi approach... it'd be good to include some comments, just in case someone comes along later and wonders why you're using seeAllData. Also, I've created an bug for the gack, so hopefully you won't even need the workaround in the future. The internal work ID is W-2428043.